# Outside Activity Disclusure Form of an incorporated contractor

Tags: contract-law, corporate-law

I've created a corporation to engage in software consulting for a major sensitive industry institution. As part of the contract paperwork to my corporation, they've presented me with a form stating I should disclose all my outside business (and otherwise time-consuming) activities to them.

My question is whether that form is directed at me as an individual, or to my corporation? (From the wording, it seems it refers to my person) Is it reasonable that I, as an individual, should report any of my outside activities (business and otherwise) to them if they're signing the agreement with my corporation?

What could be my strategy if I wanted to let them know that I don't intend to compete or undermine their business, while not having to divulge all my other unrelated activities, business and personal?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: A corporation can't be "employed" only natural people can.

Comment: Thanks, Dale! I meant as part of the paperwork that's required if the contract is to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danger. Danger. Danger.

You want to work as a contractor. You forgot to mention the place, but in most place both you and your client can get into trouble when you claim to be a contractor, but actually work exactly like an employee.

As a contractor, it is none of their business whatsoever what other jobs you do. You can work elsewhere on the weekend. You can hire ten people to do ten more jobs. It's none of their business. It is in their best interest not to ask and not to know.

If your local tax office checks, then having given this information to your client is a strong indication that you are not a contractor, but an employee. So tell your client that this is *not* something that should be put in writing.

Comment: Thank you, gnasher! That was sort of my hunch as well. I've got a few projects in various stages of completion, and the main reason for me to contract right now is not to worry about my legal standing regarding ownership of IP, profits, and disclosing other commitments.

I really wanted a clarification regarding your last point (with taxes) as well as other potential pitfalls this situation could expose me to.